# Multiple criteria Countif unable to match due to date range, importrange

Tags: google-sheets

I am attempting to build a live dashboard for our lovely mechanics to see how many services they have completed in a day. The majority of the time it will be used to only show services from a certain mechanic on today's date, however I would like to be able to change the date it shows date for and so would like to be able to grab that criteria from a certain cell in sheet.
My current thinking is that the dashboard would have a formula like this:

```
=COUNTIFS(
    IMPORTRANGE(
        "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bx65qPAChwZ8uxwJsMfh-w5uALdKVdnn8x7LXD6J3zs", 
        "Servicing!A:A"), 
    D1,
    IMPORTRANGE(
        "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bx65qPAChwZ8uxwJsMfh-w5uALdKVdnn8x7LXD6J3zs", 
        "Servicing!C:C"), 
    C7)
```

`D1` is where i can put in the date. `C7` is where the mechanics name is held. My thinking is that this is not working as the data is populated using a google form. This google form records a timestamp in the following way `'3/13/2020 12:09:56'` Meaning that It will only match this data if the exact same time matches. Is there a way to make it search for ALL records on  a date instead of all from a precise time?
Thanks for reading!

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, free of sensitive information, clearly indicating the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove the time from the google forms output by adding and extra column and using this formula
=TO_DATE(DATEVALUE(B805))
B805 is filled by the time stamp from the google form
I then made my formula search for the info in the new colum with the above in each cell. It worked! :)